# Laravel Validator always shows required error message

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

While testing, system always returning me required customized message. For example i want the validator to check if the passwords match. But error message shows me **"Password Validation is required"** instead of **"Passwords does not match"**.

Here is my validation function and rules.

```
protected function getRegisterValidator()
{
    $message = array(
        'same' => ':attribute ve :other tekrarları birbirini tutmalı.',
        'between' => ':attribute en az :min en fazla :max karakterden oluşabilir.',
        'min' => ':attribute en az :min karakter içermelidir.',
        'max' => ':attribute maksimum :max karakterden oluşabilir.',
        'alpha_num' => 'girilen :attribute alfanumerik olmalıdır.',
        'unique' => 'Bu :attribute ile zaten önceden kayıt olunmuş.',
        'email' => ':attribute geçerli bir mail adresi değil.',
        'captcha' => 'Doğrulama karakterlerini yanlış girdiniz.',
        'required' => ':attribute alanı boş olamaz.'
    );
    return Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
        'Kurum' => 'required',
        'Ad' => 'required',
        'Soyad' => 'required',
        'Görev' => 'required',
        'Email' => 'required|email|unique:user',
        'Email Tekrarı'=> 'required|same:Email',
        'Şifre' => 'required|between:8,12',
        'Şifre Tekrarı' => 'required|same:Şifre',
        'Doğrulama' => 'captcha|required'
    ), $message);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The space between field names like "Şifre Tekrarı" or "Email Tekrarı" leading an error and laravel validator cannot compare the values between "Şifre" and "Şifre Tekrarı" fields.

**The solution is setting field names without spaces in your HTML file (or blade), and it does not involve anything with Turkish characters.**

```
protected function getRegisterValidator()
{
    $message = array(
        'same' => ':attribute ve :other tekrarları birbirini tutmalı.',
        'between' => ':attribute en az :min en fazla :max karakterden oluşabilir.',
        'min' => ':attribute en az :min karakter içermelidir.',
        'max' => ':attribute maksimum :max karakterden oluşabilir.',
        'alpha_num' => 'girilen :attribute alfanumerik olmalıdır.',
        'unique' => 'Bu :attribute ile zaten önceden kayıt olunmuş.',
        'email' => ':attribute geçerli bir mail adresi değil.',
        'captcha' => 'Doğrulama karakterlerini yanlış girdiniz.',
        'required' => ':attribute alanı boş olamaz.'
    );
    return Validator::make(Input::all(),array(
        'Kurum' => 'required|min:3|max:60',
        'Ad' => 'required|min:3|max:30',
        'Soyad' => 'required|min:3|max:30',
        'Görev' => 'required|min:1|max:60',
        'Email' => 'required|email|unique:user|same:Email_Tekrarı',
        'Email_Tekrarı'=> 'required',
        'Şifre' => 'required|between:8,12|same:Şifre_Tekrarı',
        'Şifre_Tekrarı' => 'required',
        'Doğrulama' => 'captcha|required'
    ), $message);
}
```

**Important note :**

If you are showing error messages with these field names like "Email_Tekrarı" (i mean there is a _ character included) the error message ignores "_" character and shows error message as like "Email Tekrarı field is required".

Works smoothly.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$message = [
        'şifre.required' => 'Şifre alanı boş bırakılamaz',
        'şifre.same' => 'Şifre alanları eşleşmiyor',
    ];
```

"şifre" is input name.

Comment: it does not work, i think the problem is Turkish characters and also space between my input names like : "Şifre" and "Şifre Tekrarı". I'll give feedbacks after testing.

Comment: Of course it would be better if you do not use Turkish characters.But I think the problem is not related to Turkish characters. Turkish character problem though "Passwords does not match" would have not failed. I think there's another case. I'm going to test.